# Changing Permalink Settings in Wordpress gives "Fatal error: Out of memory"

Tags: wordpress, memory, permalinks, fatal-error

I tried to change the URL structure of my Wordpress site.  I am getting following error

```
"Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 31981568) (tried to allocate 1111781 bytes) in ../wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 774"
```

I researched in internet and I got this solution:

```
1. Try adding this line to your wp-config.php file:
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');

2. If you have access to your PHP.ini file, change the line in PHP.ini
If your line shows 32M try 64M:
memory_limit = 64M ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (64MB)

3. If you don't have access to PHP.ini try adding this to an .htaccess file:
php_value memory_limit 64M

4. Talk to your host.
```

Nothing worked for me,  I did not try the second option since I do not have access to php.ini file.

My Question is why changing an simple URL cause this issue?  Is this because of cache or some thing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress needs RAM. Talk to your host and ask them how much your account gets and ask for more. You might have to change hosts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..  I am just trying to change the URL Permalink is that related to RAM?

Comment: WordPress needs RAM. Changing permalinks involves database queries and CPU time, hence RAM. Ask your host how much RAM is allocated to your account.

Comment: Ok..  I will ask my hosting comp regarding this..  How much memory usually need for hosting a WP site with 300 pages.  Also I read a posting that disabling all the plugins then make the peramlink change will work.  Also I read that if the site has more than 50 pages this will happen.  What do you think about that.  It is a live site so I cant take a big risk.  Once again Thank you for your reply.